# Fast way to find median of input

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, optimization, statistics

So I am finding the median of a 'Stream' of number from the input. The input length vary from 1 to 4999999. (Given it is an odd number).

The time limit is 5 seconds.

My current code should be straightforward:

```
import statistics
array = []
n = int(input())
for _ in range(n):
    array.append(int(input()))
print (int(statistics.median(array)))
```

But I am getting TLE for some of the case. The problem should be because of the loop `for _ in range(n)` is too slow.

Is there any way to either speed up the reading input process, or to calculate the median while reading constant input?

(I know the problem is in the loop just by putting a `print ('Done')` right after looping... or is it because of the append?)

Comment: Maybe your computer is just too slow? Anyway, use a profiler to find out where most time is spent, so you can try to optimize those places. BTW: Reading a leading length doesn't follow from your description and, as the saying goes, when comments and code disagree, both are probably wrong. ;)

Comment: The code is run on the online judge and I think someone passed it with Python as well. Also I found that appending the numbers to the array should be the problem as reading and printing doesn't seem to have the problem... And what is a profiler?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html

Comment: Using the python profile, the TLE is because of reading the input. Reading 50k times takes 0.9 second... I guess python might not be the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following to be substantially faster than `input/append`:

```
import statistics
from sys import stdin
n = int(stdin.readline())  # unused below, stdin terminates on EOF
l = list(map(int, stdin.read().split()))  # read rest of file in one gulp, split & map it
print(int(statistics.median(l)))
```

Comment: It kinda works... It passed 1 more test case but the other failed ones even get Memory Limit Exceeded (Whatever you want to call it). I wonder why

Comment: So where is this online judge?  I tested the code above with 5 million inputs, with no memory limit exceeded or runtime errors.

Comment: it is an online judge from hong kong and need an account to login.

Comment: Also Memory limit is 256MB

Comment: You asked "Is there any way to either speed up the reading input process, or..." The code I provided does that.  You didn't mention other constraints.

Comment: But actually it is significantly faster. (It takes 0.000 second)

Answer (score 0):

Several things you can do:

- stop calling lists arrays

Streamline the input:

```
numbers = sorted(map(int, (input() for _ in range(int(input()))))
```

Calculate the median yourself:

```
def median(nums:list) : 
    l = len(nums)

    if l%2 == 1:
        return nums[l//2]
    else:
        return sum(nums[l//2-1:l//2+1])/2
```

In total:

```
print(median(sorted(map(int, (input() for _ in range(int(input())))))))
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't seem to work. Using the python profile, the TLE is because of reading the input. Reading 50k times takes 0.9 second... I guess python might not be the way to do it, sorry. Thanks for your solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a 'standard answer', I just switched to C++ and get it passed easily.

(Yes I learnt it in 30 minutes).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int CalcMHWScore(vector<int> scores)
{
  size_t size = scores.size();

  if (size == 0)
  {
    return 0;  // Undefined, really.
  }
  else if (size == 1)
  {
    return scores[0];
  }
  else
  {
    sort(scores.begin(), scores.end());
    if (size % 2 == 0)
    {
      return (scores[size / 2 - 1] + scores[size / 2]) / 2;
    }
    else 
    {
      return scores[size / 2];
    }
  }
}

int main() {
   int lengths;
   cin >> lengths;
   std::vector<int> a(lengths);
   for (unsigned i=0; i<lengths; i++)
   {
   int u;
   cin >> u;
   a[i]=u;
   }
   cout << CalcMHWScore(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient implementation in python could be done using numpy 
and generators:

```
import numpy as np

n = int(input())
array = np.fromiter((int(input()) for _ in range(n)), np.int32)
print(int(np.median(array)))
```

However, since there is no way for me to check this new solution with the online judge it is not clear if it would be fast enough.

Comment: Running the code(or any code in Python) with a input size of around 5k takes 0.014 seconds to even read the input... (using cProfile) (@tio.run)